# Смещается фокус в компоненте TMemo при добавлении текста

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-berlin

При добавлении текста из файла в компонент TMemo(прокрутка текста в компоненте включена), фокус возвращается на начало, т. е. компонент прокручивается назад. Ввод текста производится следующим образом:

```
while not Eof(MainArray[1,1].F) do
begin
  Readln(MainArray[1,1].F, s);
  Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + s + #13#10;
end;
```

Можно ли отключить эту возможность программно или через свойства?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Странное у вас добавление текста, которое приводит к лишней работе. Чтобы добавить строку, делается просто `Memo.Lines.Add(s)`. Но загрузка файла целиком ещё проще,  текстовый файл не нужен совсем - `Lines.Loadfromfile`

Comment: Вы немного не поняли, мне нужно дополнять Memo все новым текстом из файла. При использовании LoadFromFile предыдущее содержимое стирается

Comment: Я же написал про Memo.Lines.Add(s)    (а если весь файл целиком добавить AddStrings из загруженного TStringList)